# Why the angular-js ng-option not showing as selected?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-select

```
<select ng-model="field.value" class="form-control" ng-attr-name="{{name}}">
            <option selected="selected">{{field.fieldName}}</option>
            <option ng-repeat="app in field.attributes.split(',')" value="{{app}}">{{app}}</option>
</select>
```

In this code, my expected behaviour is , it will show the select box and it select the first option I have added selected="selected".

but it not selecting that "selected" attribute element.

I have tried this with ng-selected="true" also. It also not help for me. any suggestion for me?

Comment: you can use <option value="" >your value</option> to show the first value as selected

Comment: @Abhishekkumar, it doest work for me. anyway, the tymeJV solution was worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the `ngOptions` directive - not a `ngRepeat` on an `option` element:

```
<select ng-model="field.value" ng-options="app as app for app in field.attributes.split(',')" class="form-control" ng-attr-name="{{name}}"></select>
```

Now simply set your `ngModel` (`field.value`) to the field you want selected.